# Makefile target with makefile as dependency

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I am currently working on a project where I have a couple applications in a parent folder that need to be rebuilt whenever the libraries contained in child folders are updated. The apps in the parent folder are built with a makefile, and the libraries are built with a separate makefile in the respective folder. This looks something like :

- ParentDir

  - app1
  - app2
  - Makefile

    - libdir1

      - Makefile
    - libdir2

      - Makefile

I'm currently doing something like this for my makefile in the parent dir

```
all : app1 app2

libs = libdir1/lib1.a libdir2/lib2.a
.PHONY : $(libs)


$(all) : $(libs)
    #do stuff to make the apps

libdir1/lib1.a : 
    $(MAKE) -c libdir1


libdir2/lib2.a : 
    $(MAKE) -c libdir2
```

My problem is, I don't want the apps in the parent dir's makefile to rebuild unless one of the makefiles it "depends" on are updated. I know that the reason this is happening currently is that I have my libs declared as PHONY ( so they always rebuild ), but that was the only way I could figure out to actually call the children makefiles.

So, what I want is for each app to build only when either of the libdirs makefile's would actually do something, and to call each libdir's makefile that would "do something" before building the app.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make a dummy dependency for the libraries so that their Makefiles are always processed. Here is a good example and explanation: http://owen.sj.ca.us/~rk/howto/slides/make/slides/makerecurs.html

Comment: A very good reference for larger makefile-built projects. Thanks much. I'll come back and upvote your answer when I have enough rep ;)

Comment: Or read "Recursive Make Considered Harmful" and consider using the better style suggested therein.